# Self join for two same rows with one different column

Tags: sql

Hi I have table with the following data

```
A      B     bid  status
10     20    1    SUCCESS_1
10     20    1    SUCCESS_2
10     30    2    SUCCESS_1
10     30    2    SUCCESS_2
```

Now I want to print or count above rows based on SUCCESS_1 and SUCCESS_2. I created the following query but it does not work it just returns one row by combining two rows.

```
select * from tbl t1  join tbl t2 on
on (t1.A=t2.A and t1.B=t2.B and
(t1.Status = 'SUCCESS_1' and t2.Status = 'SUCCESS_2')
where t1.bid= 1
```

I want output as the following for the above query

```
 A      B     bid  status
    10     20    1    SUCCESS_1
    10     20    1    SUCCESS_2
```

I am new to SQL please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the exact output you desire.

Comment: @juergend please see added comment. Sorry for incomplete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do the join for some reason (e.g. your database does not let you select everything if you group by 1 column, because it wants everything projected to either be grouped or be an aggregate), you could do the following:

```
select t1.* 
from tbl t1  join tbl t2
on (t1.A=t2.A and t1.B=t2.B and t1.Status = 'SUCCESS_1' and t2.Status = 'SUCCESS_2')
where t1.bid= 1
union all select t2.* 
from tbl t1  join tbl t2
on (t1.A=t2.A and t1.B=t2.B and t1.Status = 'SUCCESS_1' and t2.Status = 'SUCCESS_2')
where t1.bid= 1
order by 1,2,3,4
```

Your original query is pulling back all the data in one row, but this one pulls back the two rows that make that resulting join row separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl1` WHERE `bid`=1 GROUP BY `status`
```